# Errors checking and opening a URL using PHP

Tags: php

Here is one script with out any errors

```
$url="http://yahoo.com";
$file1 = fopen($url, "r");
$content = file_get_contents($url); 


$t_beg = explode('<title>',$content);
$t_end = explode('</title>',$t_beg[1]);
echo $t_end[0];
```

And here is the same script using a look to check multiple urls and getting errors

```
    for ($j=1;$j<=$i;$j++) {
    if ($x[$j]!=''){

    $t_u = "http:".$x[$j];

    $file2 = fopen($t_u, "r");


        $content2 = file_get_contents($t_u); 
        $t_beg = explode('<title>',$content);
        $t_end = explode('</title>',$t_beg[1]);
                echo $t_end[0];

     }
  }
```

The error is **Warning: fopen() [function.fopen]: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in g:/**

What exactly is wrong here?

Comment: Depends - what URLs are you checking? Also I notice that you add onto http: rather than http:// - is that intentional, are you storing //flibble.com instead of flibble.com?

Comment: thats intentional
any urls, all the urls are valid and some were checked at random for errors, no error though

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is wrong here

1. Getting someone's info without permission. If site willing to give a page away, it will provide an RSS.
2. "Checking" unexistent domains.

Comment: Not the point @col sharpnel, I want to know what the error is, who wants site info

Answer (score 0):

Just before you attempt a fopen:

```
$file2 = fopen($t_u, "r");
```

Echo the value of `$t_u` and make sure it is correct.

Comment: did the echo, displays it fine

Answer (score 0):

I have a version of this script working - it implies that perhaps your data is wrong. You could do a DNS lookup on the domain before trying to get the contents of the URL. In essence you're missing some error checking:

```
<?php

$x = array('//yahoo.com', '//google.com', '//leenux.org.uk');
$i = 3;

for ($j=0;$j<$i;$j++) {
    if ($x[$j]!=''){
        $t_u = "http:".$x[$j];

        $content2 = file_get_contents($t_u); 

        if (preg_match("/\\<title\\>(.*)\\<\\/title\\>/", $content2, $matches)) {
            echo $matches[1];
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would first check the setting for allow_url_fopen in the php.ini file on this server.

Comment: if allow_url_fopen is not permitted then the first script would not run.  Its a 127.0.0.1 server.